# SSH Android Studio connected to RaspberryPi , unknown problem

Tags: java, android, ssh

recently ive started working on program that will send commands to my raspberry via SSH , i had many problems but i found solutions to them , but this time i dont know what problem is . If you can point me in right direction,that would be great

The code

```
    package com.example.buhu.ssh2;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.lang.Object.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            executeRemoteCommand("pi", "123","192.168.0.115", 22);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }



       });
thread.start();

    }



    public  String executeRemoteCommand(String username,String password,String hostname,int port)
            throws Exception {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
                session.openChannel("exec");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Execute command
        channelssh.setCommand("ls");
        channelssh.connect();
        channelssh.disconnect();

        return baos.toString();
}
    });
    }
}
```

and the AndroidStudio output

```
10/31 16:46:46: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.example.buhu.ssh2 C:\Users\Buhu\AndroidStudioProjects\SSH\SSH2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\Buhu\AndroidStudioProjects\SSH\SSH2\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed in 3 s 294 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.buhu.ssh2/com.example.buhu.ssh2.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 25524 on device samsung-sm_g920f-01157df1b5c6a91a
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/Zygote: v2
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10316
    KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0010, [-1 -1 -4 -1 0 1]
I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.buhu.ssh2 
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/lib/arm64
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.buhu.ssh2.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:21)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.buhu.ssh2-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/co
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.buhu.ssh2.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:21)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=70
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@83f7742[MainActivity] touchMode=true
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 535550076416} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
    mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 535550076416} hwInitialized=true
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 535550076416}
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1d385a8 nm : com.example.buhu.ssh2 ic=null
I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=82
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1b948c1 nm : com.example.buhu.ssh2 ic=null
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 535550076416} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@aad498d[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

The only error that i think its error is

```
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

but i dont know what it means ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in **appcompat-v7** library for **SdkVersion 28**.

Either change your `styles.xml` to let *AppTheme* inherit from `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` rather than `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Change:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Or change targeted **SDKVersion** to `27` in `project folder > app > build.gradle(Module: app)`.

Change:

```
minSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

to:

```
minSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Comment: sadly ,thats not it , still the same problem